# uniform convergence of Dirichlet eta function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, dirichlet-series

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, define a series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{x}},$$ which is called the Dirichlet eta function from the complex analysis.

It converges pointwise on $(0,\infty)$ trivially.

I wonder about that what is the range for which converges uniformly?

By the little knowledge for complex analysis, it seems to be uniformly on any compact subset of $(0,\infty)$.

Is it possible to extend the range for uniform as $[\varepsilon,\infty)$? (where $\varepsilon>0$ is an arbitrary real number)

Give some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Dirichlet Discriminance.

Comment: The series does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ for the same reason that $\frac1{n^x}$ does not converge to $0$ uniformly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\sum(-1)^{n}a_n$ converges if $a_n$ decreases to $0$. The proof of this theorem  actually gives something stronger: if $f_n(x)$ decreases to $0$ uniformly for $x$ in some set $A$ then $\sum(-1)^{n}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $A$. From this it is obvious that the given series converge uniformly for $ x\in [\epsilon, \infty)$ [ since $\frac 1 {n^{x}} \leq \frac 1 {n^{\epsilon}}]$.

Comment: The first line is wrong or missing details.

Comment: The first line is the alternating series test. Why is it wrong?

Comment: It is not the alternating test. Consider $a_n=1/n$ when $n$ is even and $1/n^2$ when $n$ is odd, for example.

Comment: Your sequence is not decreasing.

Comment: Ah my bad, the compact wording of "decreasing to 0" got me.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Does $\frac1{n^x}$ converge uniformly to $0$ on $(0,1)$?  What is the value of the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}$?

Comment: I don’t think this is the question.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The OP is asking about the UC of the Dirichlet Eta Function.  One test for the UC of a series is that it's terms approach $0$ uniformly.  So, what did I miss?

Comment: That they don't care about $(0,\infty),$ rather $[\epsilon,\infty)$ for aribitrary $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen No, that is not true.  I quote "Is it possible to extend the range for uniform as $[\epsilon,\infty)$ (where $\epsilon>0$ is an arbitrary real number)?"  The OP already knows that the series is UC on $[\epsilon,\infty)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I think they want to extend the range from "any compact subset of $(0,\infty)$" to "$[\epsilon, \infty)$". The fact that they say they are aware it is UC on any compact subset and that their alternative is $[\epsilon,\infty)$ indicates to me that they are aware that it does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty).$

Comment: In other words, you are interpreting the preposition "as" in their second to last line as "from", I think the more reasonable interpretation based on the previous paragraph is "to".

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The OP is asking whether we can extend the interval on which the series is UC from $[\epsilon,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$.  That is fairly evident from the language in the original post.

Comment: There's no point arguing about this further. There is now an answer to both my and your interpretation of the question and OP can clarify.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The other answer precisely aligns with what I have been saying.  I am unsure as to the disconnect here.

Comment: The other answer shows that it is uniformly convergent on $[\epsilon,\infty)$ which is how I'm interpreting the question. OP claims to know it converges uniformly on any compact set, e.g. $[\epsilon,1]$ and wants to know if the right endpoint can be extended to $\infty.$ You may well be right that they actually care about extending the left endpoint to zero... I think the question can be read both ways... but I'm really at a loss as to how the interpretation I'm making isn't clear and it how isn't clear how Kavi is answering a different question that agrees with my interpretation.

Comment: Anyway, I shouldn't have bit there and I promise this is my last time commenting here... we all agree which sets it converges uniformly on and which it doesn't, and it's pointless to argue over what OP meant when they can just clarify.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see your point now.  And you might very well be correct.  It just seemed so obvious that UC applies out to infinity (M-test for $x>1$).